# Javascript ||, how to compare multiple variables value?

Tags: javascript, operators, comparator

How to right this syntax correctly:

```
if (tipoTropaPrioritaria[m] || troopsCount[m] || availableTroops[m]) == ("null" || "undefined") {

...

}
```

(to check if any of the first 3 variables is null or undefined)

Comment: Do you mean the values `null` and `undefined` or the string values `"null"` and `"undefined"`?

Comment: not string values, the "internal javascript" null/undefined value.

Comment: Remember to accept a solution when you are satisfied.

Answer (score 3):

You could define a small helper function that does the check and then use it on all the values:

```
function notset(v) {
   return (v === undefined) || (v === null);
}

if (notset(tipoTropaPrioritaria[m]) || notset(troopsCount[m]) ||
    notset(availableTroops[m])) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: @Lucas: I guess those should work, but probably it would be more readable to use a named function instead of defining it "inline".

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
if (tipoTropaPrioritaria[m] == null || troopsCount[m] == null || availableTroops[m] == null || 
    tipoTropaPrioritaria[m] == undefined || troopsCount[m] == undefined || availableTroops[m] == undefined) {
    // ...
}
```

**EDIT**: It's probably better to use the `===` (threequals) operator in this case.

```
if (tipoTropaPrioritaria[m] === null || troopsCount[m] === null || availableTroops[m] === null || 
    tipoTropaPrioritaria[m] === undefined || troopsCount[m] === undefined || availableTroops[m] === undefined) {
    // ...
}
```

or:

```
if (null in {tipoTropaPrioritaria[m]:0, troopsCount[m]:0, availableTroops[m]:0} || undefined in {tipoTropaPrioritaria[m]:0, troopsCount[m]:0, availableTroops[m]:0}) {
```

Comment: You should use `typeof foo == "undefined"` as undefined can be set as a variable with a different value.

Comment: what is typeof foo and why should I use it?

Comment: i´m going to use if (null in {tipoTropaPrioritaria[m]:0, troopsCount[m]:0, availableTroops[m]:0} || undefined in {tipoTropaPrioritaria[m]:0, troopsCount[m]:0, availableTroops[m]:0})


should I use typeof foo ??

Comment: Ah. I was worried this trick might not work with the more complicated expressions. Give me a couple of minutes and I'll try to find a work-around.

Comment: I don't think there's a simple workaround - I'd use one of the simpler versions either in my answer or another. http://pastebin.com/8Q5NJCjL contains a possible one if you really want to use the second way I demonstrated, but it's more of an academic exercise than something that should actually be used.

Comment: Your object property example won’t work: `var x=null; x in {x:0}` yields *false*.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best way to do what you want

```
if (!tipoTropaPrioritaria[m] || !troopsCount[m] || !availableTroops[m]) {
    ...
}
```

The `!` operator coerces the result into a boolean that can be tested for (null and undefined becomes false), and with the `!` in front `false` is negated into `true`.

The other way to do it is to test each expression against `null` and `undefined`.

```
function isNullOrUndefined(val) {
    return (val === null || typeof val == "undefined"); 
}    

if (isNullOrUndefined(a) || isNullOrUndefined(b) ... ) {
```

And so you know it, the correct way to test for undefined is

```
if (typeof foo === "undefined") {...
```

Comment: I think you mean `==`, not `=`.

Comment: Be careful with the non-specific test. A non-null boolean value of **false** will be treated the same as **null** unless you test for undefined/null.

Comment: The only problem with this is that `availableTroops[m]` might legitimately be 0, which might need a different behavior than null or undefined.

Comment: @John: No, === is the way to go!!

Comment: @Claudio: it is guaranteed that `typeof` returns a string, so `===` is not needed.

Comment: if I use if (!tipoTropaPrioritaria[m] || !troopsCount[m] || !availableTroops[m]) {
    ...
}

I believe I can have problems if the value of one of the variables is 0. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, you are absolutely right; so in this case you should go for a function like `isSet` or `isNullOrUndefined` mentioned in the answers.
But in your case, will `0` be treated different than not being set? Often 0 and not set can be treated as the same.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do is:

```
if ((tipoTropaPrioritaria[m] == null || tipoTropaPrioritaria[m] == undefined)
|| (troopsCount[m] == null || troopsCount[m] == undefined) ||
(availableTroops[m] == null || availableTroops[m] == undefined)) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do this a lot you can create a helper function

```
function isNullOrUndef(args) {
    for (var i =0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (arguments[i] == null || typeof arguments[i] === "undefined") {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

if (isNullOrUndef(tipoTropaPrioritaria[m], troopsCount[m], availableTroops[m]))
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (tipoTropaPrioritaria[m] && troopsCount[m] && availableTroops[m]) { }
else { /* At least ones is undefined/null OR FALSE */ }

if (tipoTropaPrioritaria[m] == null || troopsCount[m] == null || availableTroops[m] == null)
{ /* One is null. */ }
```

Comment: What happens if one of them is `0` in the first code snippet?

Comment: @Matt That's what the "OR FALSE" comment was meant to address (zero, false, null)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check if they are null or undefined you can write

```
if (!tipoTropaPrioritaria[m] || !troopsCount[m] || !availableTroops[m])
```

both *null* and `undefined` are **falsely** values. Then this will only be true if none of this are *null* or *undefined*.
Please consider that there are other falsely values as well:

- 0
- empty string
- NaN